# Playwright - Find multiple elements or class names

Tags: javascript, typescript, automation, browser-automation, playwright

I have read a few different QAs related to this but none seem to be working.

I am trying to target an element (Angular) called mat-radio-button with a class called mat-radio-checked. And then select the inner text.

In Chrome this is easy:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ev0iQ.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/lVoG3.png

To find the first element that matches in Playwright I can do something like:

```
      let test: any = await page.textContent(
      "mat-radio-button.mat-radio-checked"
    );

    console.log(test);
```

But if I try this:

```
      let test: any = await page.$$(
      "mat-radio-button.mat-radio-checked"
    );

    console.log(test);
    console.log(test[0]);
    console.log(test[1]);
  });
```

It does not return an array of elements I can select the inner text of.

I need to be able to find all elements with that class so I can use expect to ensure the returned inner text is correct, eg:

```
    expect(test).toBe("Australian Citizen");
```

Comment: This code worked for me https://gist.github.com/kblok/19b60e76197c4d8aebaba650b2b1af93 what's different there?

Comment: Hi @hardkoded - you're response helped me. But see my answer to what the main issue was.

Answer (score 4):

I found out the issue was due to the page generating beforehand and the elements were not available. So I added a waitForSelector:

```
await page.waitForSelector("mat-radio-button");

const elements = await page.$$("mat-radio-button.mat-radio-checked");
console.log(elements.length);
console.log(await elements[0].innerText());
console.log(await elements[1].innerText());
console.log(await elements[2].innerText());
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  public async validListOfItems(name) {
  await this.page.waitForSelector(name, {timeout: 5000});
  const itemlists = await this.page.$$(name);

  let allitems: string[]=new Array();

    for await (const itemlist of itemlists) {
        allitems.push(await itemlist.innerText());
    }
  return allitems;
  }
```

Make a common method and call by sending parameters.

Answer (score 1):

Approaches in existing answers are no longer considered idiomatic Playwright. The current preferred approach is to use locators, which [auto-wait](https://playwright.dev/docs/actionability) for the element(s) to be available. Locators usually mitigate the need for `page.$` and `waitForSelector`, wich are legacy Puppeteer-style methods.

To extract text from a locator matching more than one element, you can use [`allTextContents`](https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-locator#locator-all-text-contents):

```js
const playwright = require("playwright"); // 1.30.0

let browser;
(async () => {
  browser = await playwright.chromium.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.setContent(`<p>a</p><p>b</p>`);
  console.log(await page.locator("p").allTextContents()); // => [ 'a', 'b' ]
})()
  .catch(err => console.error(err))
  .finally(() => browser?.close());
```

Now, you mention:

> I need to be able to find all elements with that class so I can use expect to ensure the returned inner text is correct, eg:
>
> ```js
> expect(test).toBe("Australian Citizen");
> ```

In this case, use [`toHaveText`](https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-locatorassertions#locator-assertions-to-have-text), a [web-first assertion](https://playwright.dev/docs/best-practices#use-web-first-assertions):

```js
import {expect, test} from "@playwright/test"; // ^1.30.0

test("has the right text", async ({page}) => {
  await page.setContent("<p>a</p><p>a</p>");
  await expect(page.locator("p")).toHaveText(["a", "a"]);
});
```

If you have a ton of elements, all with the same text, even if you're not sure how many are there in advance:

```js
test("has the right text", async ({page}) => {
  await page.setContent("<p>a</p>".repeat(30));
  const loc = page.locator("p");
  const quantity = await loc.count();
  await expect(loc).toHaveText(Array(quantity).fill("a"));
});
```