# Getting this error strict mode violation on multiple locators in playwright

Tags: typescript, playwright

Are there other ways to check values from multiple elements with the same locator?

Getting th    is error:

> strict mode violation: locator('.count')

This is my method to validate the data from api response

```
const validateFieldValue = async (field, page) => {
     await expect(page.locator(".count")).toHaveText(`${field}`);
  };
```

The values of the different elements in the page are stored in the locator having the same class name (i.e. class = "count").

This is where I call the validateFieldValue method.

```
await page.route("**/graph?Date=**", async (route) => {
        if (route.request().method() !== 'GET') {
            await route.fallback();
            return;
        }
        
        // Make the original request
        const response = await route.fetch();
        //const jp = require("jsonpath");

        // Get the response
        const result = await response.json();
        const respBody = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(result));
        expect(response.status()).toBe(200);
        expect(respBody["test"]).not.toBeNull;
        expect(respBody).toHaveProperty(child1);
        
        //Validate fields in Rate
        fieldValue.push(respBody["test"]["rate"]["passed"],
                        respBody["test"]["rate"]["manually_passed"],
                        respBody["test"]["rate"]["needs_attention"],
                        respBody["test"]["rate"]["failed"],
                        respBody["test"]["rate"]["manually_failed"],
                        respBody["test"]["rate"]["pending"],
        )

        //Validate fields in Level
        fieldValue.push(respBody["test"]["level"]["low"],
                        respBody["test"]["level"]["medium"],
                        respBody["test"]["level"]["high"],
                        respBody["test"]["level"]["unacceptable"],
                        respBody["test"]["level"]["unknown"]
        )

        //Validate fields in First Check
        fieldValue.push(count,
                        jp.query(respBody["test"]["check"], "$[?(@.type =='DL')].count"),
                        jp.query(respBody["test"]["check"], "$[?(@.type =='VL')].count")
                        jp.query(respBody["test"]["check"], "$[?(@.type =='CL')].count")
        )

        //Validate fields in Last Check
        fieldValue.push(jp.query(respBody["test"]["check"], "$[?(@.type =='KC')].count"),
                        jp.query(respBody["test"]["check"], "$[?(@.type =='PP')].count"),
                        jp.query(respBody["test"]["check"], "$[?(@.type =='WL')].count"),
                        jp.query(respBody["test"]["check"], "$[?(@.type =='S')].count"),
                        jp.query(respBody["test"]["check"], "$[?(@.type =='AM')].count"),
                        jp.query(respBody["test"]["check"], "$[?(@.type =='FL')].count")
        )


        validateFieldValue(fieldValue, page)

        return route.continue();
   });
```

Comment: Can you share an example of the HTML and a description of what you're trying to asset, exactly? Usually, you'd pass in an array of text contents.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Playwright - Find multiple elements or class names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66702513/playwright-find-multiple-elements-or-class-names)

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76037410/6243352).

Answer (score 0):

This means that your selector is matching more than one element and playwright doesn't know which one to perform the action on.

So there must be more than one element that has count as a class.  You can choosing a more unique reference to the element, or you can use one of the the multi-element locator methods such as `page.locator(".count").first()` to narrow down the matches.

[According to playwright docs](https://playwright.dev/docs/locators#strictness):

> Locators are strict. This means that all operations on locators that imply some target DOM element will throw an exception if more than one element matches....

> On the other hand, Playwright understands when you perform a multiple-element operation, so the following call works perfectly fine when the locator resolves to multiple elements....

> You can explicitly opt-out from strictness check by telling Playwright which element to use when multiple elements match, through `locator.first()`, `locator.last()`, and `locator.nth()`...

Comment: yeah I've researched about that but what I really wanted to do is to have a dynamic method in which I don't want to specify the specific nth locator. In cypress that method perfectly works fine, we are migrating our codes into playwright and I'm having that problem now

Comment: Maybe my another question would be "how to count number of elements with the same locator in playwright"?

Comment: @simpleMan Are you looking to assert their count or text contents? If the first, `expect(loc).toHaveCount(42)`. If the second, `expect(loc).toHaveText(["a", "b", "c", ...])`.

Comment: @ggorlen I am getting below

Error: expect(locator).toHaveText(expected)

Locator: locator('.count')
Expected string: "455,2,357,725,13,30,6303,596,944,21,0,1,17,16,151,6,,,,20"
Received string: ""
Call log:
  - expect.toHaveText with timeout 120000ms
  - waiting for locator('.count')


  21 |     }*/
  22 |
> 23 |     await expect(await page.locator(".count")).toHaveText(`${field}`);

Comment: @simpleMan Please share a [mcve] as an edit to your post. There's not enough information to help here.

Comment: @simpleMan Thanks, but still not quite complete or runnable. Multiple problems are apparent though: `validateFieldValue(fieldValue, page)` is never `await`ed. Secondly, you're passing an array as `fieldValue` which seems to expect a single value. There are probably other issues, and the overall pattern looks strange. Please share a complete example, with a sample target page (or the actual page under test). `//const jp = require("jsonpath");` is commented out.